# Wordpress redirects to home page

Tags: wordpress

When I edit/publish pages or posts, change permalinks settings etc wordpress automatically redirects me to home page and the changes are not saved too.
I did a fresh install, tried deactivating all plugins and nothing helped! And there are no redirection plugins installed. Seems like a strange issue. Any help?

Comment: did you cleared cache and checked ?

Comment: yes, it didnt help. I tried different browsers too

Comment: tried switching theme ? use default theme.

Comment: tried... didnt help!

Comment: local or live development? php version? did you update wp?

Comment: its on live server, php version 5.4.41 and with latest wordpress installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. We just need to disable MOD_SECURITY and everything will work. I have contacted my host to do it and everything worked like charm!

Answer (score 1):

I just had something very similar to this happen to me two days ago, nothing is saved, nothing can be deleted and sometimes I can't even log in. The error_log file says something, something php code 28 and it turns out the /tmp disk of my server was full.

If you check your error_log file and there's code 28 there then it's a server issue regarding the /tmp directory or disk. Other than that I don't have enough info to help you out, but it would help if you could post what's in the error_log.

Comment: Hi, I tried it, there is no code 28 and the memory is fine too. still no luck!!! But thanks for your unique idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Repair database tables by following steps.
Backup your database before doing it.
1.Login to phpMyAdmin
2.Choose the affected database. If you only have one database, it should choose it by default so you don't need to do anything.
3.In the main panel, you should see a list of your database tables. Check the boxes by the tables that need repair.
4.At the bottom of the window just below the list of tables, there is a drop down menu. Choose "Repair Table"
6.This should fix your table, and let you access it again.

Comment: Hi, it didnt fix the problem